# ProgressBar in ActionBar on Android L Preview

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-progressbar, android-5.0-lollipop

Today I started porting an app to Android L preview in order to have it almost ready when the final product launches. One problem I found is that I can't have an indeterminate progressbar on the ActionBar. It doesn't show at all and throws this error on logcat:

```
E/PhoneWindow﹕ Circular progress bar not located in current window decor
```

I'm using this code, which works in <4.4:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

Is there any way to get it working again in Android L or should I use an external ProgressBar?

Comment: I just checked the ApiDemos project (Views > ProgressBar > In Title Bar) and I got the same thing. Could be a bug.

Comment: Sounds like a bug with the new Toolbar implementation of ActionBar. Please file a bug at https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/wiki/FilingIssues?tm=3.

Comment: I'll do that. Thanks.

Comment: can you add a link to the bug report?

Comment: Here you have it: https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=891&q=progressbar&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just found this question and checked [the bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=891&q=progressbar&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary).

It seems that the dev team had concluded that the issue won't be fixed.

That is:

> intended as the progress bar features are not supported on Material action bars.

The "Material action bar" should mean 4.4 (API19) or later's action bar.