# show progress spinner actionbar android L api 21

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-design

respected developers,
how to show progress spinner in actionbar **android L** and below with appcompat.i have added toolbar widget.v7

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
 setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(Boolean.TRUE);
```

if it is wrong or is there any other approach please guide me with complete steps.i'm using Eclipse for developing.

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ProgressBar in ActionBar on Android L Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24823029/progressbar-in-actionbar-on-android-l-preview?rq=1)

on seeing this issue! a user filed a bug in official android developer Bug report forum !

https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=891&q=progressbar&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary

and the project member reported that

> Thank you for providing this feedback. We have taken a look at the issue and concluded that this is currently working as intended as the progress bar features are not supported on Material action bars. This should throw an exception if you try to use them.

if someone finds/fix the issue pls comment/answer!
thanks!

Comment: Same thing with me, not sure why they removed that feature and gave absolutely no explanation why they simply removed it from the material design. It should contain at least an explanation why they decided to remove it, and, then, a way to display the progress indication in a different way. I am watching this as things proceed. Thanks

Comment: yeah! it would be better if they add reason !
however how did u solve the problem! can u help me in adding loading spinner(progress) as like gmail! thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

we have committed endless progress bar in the toolbar and control its visibility. The only variable are the menu items present in your application

Comment: can u show any example for loading spinner in material theme ?
other than actionbar!
i have seen in Gmail/Playstore loading spinner updated with material design !